# find out which page is not published in Pages list

Tags: 2013, site-column, spfield, pages

I have a publishing site and about 20 pages in Pages list. When you check out one page the icon is changed and you detect that that page is checked out. However when there is a unpublished page it is not possible to see it, when you go to Pages list. How do I make a text field (column) which shows publish status of the page (item)?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the 'Approval Status' field in conjunction with Version field in order to find what you are looking for.  For example, an Approval Status of 'Draft' but with a version of 4.5 tells you that there is a published version available (4.0) but that the page is still being revised (Draft).  If this is a new site then you especially want to be on the lookout for anything with a version of less than 1.0 as it means that there is no published version of that page at all and will return the dreaded 404 when requested by anyone without edit permissions.

Comment: I cannot find Approval Status field, is it a existing field?

Comment: Is there a way to change the icon when it has been checkedin but not published

Comment: Publishing libraries require approval by default but if this has been turned off then the field will not be visible.  Also, there is no way to change the icon as that is based on the type of document (page) not the status.